# Submitting a Google Docs form in C#

Tags: c#, forms

I previously found the [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/143208/How-to-submit-Google-Docs-Form-by-using-C) about how to submit google docs forms via C#.

It seems that, since that was written, the method has broken, however.

If I use the actual online form, it updates immediately (without refreshing even). But if I use this method, it returns success, but no data ever shows up.

Anyone know how to do this now?

Answer (score 2):

Change formkey string and try this:

```
string formkey = <your form key>;
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
var keyval = new NameValueCollection();
keyval.Add("entry.0.single", "aaa");
keyval.Add("entry.1.single", "bbb");
Uri uri = new Uri("https://spreadsheets.google.com/spreadsheet/formResponse?formkey="+formkey);
wc.UploadValuesAsync(uri, "POST", keyval, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a hack, as your linked (broken?) solution is, so a little heavier. But Google provides an [API](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html) for Google Docs.

Answer (score 0):

the provided [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/143208/How-to-submit-Google-Docs-Form-by-using-C) is updated. 
however as google is moving from google docs to google drive, you need to make some modification to adapt to changes.